# ¿Cómo implementar dos DatePicker en un solo Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, date-format

Mi problema es que seguí [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33BFCdL0Di0) para crear un DatePicker en mi app, resulta que quiero dos pero el video sólo muestra cómo manejar uno.

Para dejarlo más claro, uno es para la fecha inicial y el otro es para la fecha límite. Cada fecha se asigna a distintos TextView. Les dejo mi código, que es casi el mismo que el del video.

```
private void inicializar() {
    fechaInicial = findViewById(R.id.objetivos_nuevo_fechaInicialText);
    fechaLimite = findViewById(R.id.objetivos_nuevo_fechaFinalText);

    fechaInicial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });

    fechaLimite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    String dame = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(c.getTime());
}
```

Aprovechando la pregunta, luego de obtener dichas fechas y guardarlas en variables, de qué manera podría validar que la fecha inicial no sea más vieja que la de límite (Ejemplo: Inicial = 1/05/2020 Límite = 1/01/2020).

Y, añadiendo una tercera duda, cómo puedo ponerlo en este formato '1/01/2020' 'día/mes/año'.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para responder tu pregunta voy a tratar de explicarme los partes :).

1.- Se puede filtrar el resultado del calendar picker con el tag, como puedes observar, cuando llamas a `datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");` el segundo parámetro le pasas un String, ese String es un tag, trátalo como si fuera un identificador. Entonces, bajo ese concepto, podemos hacer el siguiente código.

```
private void inicializar() {
    fechaInicial = findViewById(R.id.objetivos_nuevo_fechaInicialText);
    fechaLimite = findViewById(R.id.objetivos_nuevo_fechaFinalText);

    fechaInicial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fromDate");
        }
    });

    fechaLimite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "toDate");
        }
    });
 }

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(day).append("/")
           .append(month).append("/")
           .append(year);

    String text= builder.toString();

    FragmentManager fragmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag("fromDate") != null) {
        //Asumiendo que tu textview para mostrar la fecha inicial es fromDate            
        fromdate.setText(text);
    }
    if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag("toDate") != null) {
        //Asumiendo que tu textview para mostrar la fecha final es toDate            
        toDate.setText(text);
    }
}
```

2.- Ahora para validar las fechas, existen muchas maneras, la más fácil y útil que encuentro es transformar las fechas a milisegundos, de tal manera podemos comparar como si fuera un numero entero. Entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente. Imaginenos que el tu activity y/o Fragment declaraste dos variables para almacenar la fecha de inicio y la fecha de salida. Llamaremos a estas variables `startDate` y `endDate` entonces agregaremos los valores respectivos en el método donde se obtiene la fecha.

```
 @Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);


    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(day).append("/")
           .append(month).append("/")
           .append(year);

    String text= builder.toString();

    FragmentManager fragmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag("fromDate") != null) {
        //Asumiendo que tu textview para mostrar la fecha inicial es fromDate            
        fromdate.setText(text);
        startDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
    if(fragmanager.findFragmentByTag("toDate") != null) {
        //Asumiendo que tu textview para mostrar la fecha final es toDate            
        toDate.setText(text);
        endDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

Entonces, lo que te queda es validar si `startDate < endDate` para saber si la fecha inicial es menor que la final

3.- Para ponerlo en el formato que deseas, puedes construirlo a partir de un StringBuilder y agregar tus separadores. En la respuesta [1] se puede observar como le agregué los separadores "/"
 Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Probé tu código, me funcionó pero con un ligero error. Antes tuve que arreglar algunas pequeñeces (como el nombre de algunas variables y cosas así) pero al final me da mal el mes. Por ejemplo: estamos a 25/05/2020, pero en ves de darme un '5' para el mes me da un '4', o sea 25/4/2020. Y cuando pruebo con enero me da 1/0/2021. ¿Qué está mal? Aún no he probado la segunda parte de tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el datepicker, el mes lo cuenta a partir de 0. entonces lo que deberías hacer es sumarle 1 a lo que te responde el mes del date picker :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo me sirvió. Me salvaste. Bueno aún tengo muchas otras consultas, espero que me sigas ayudando XD

Comment: No hay problema, la próxima preguntas por separado :D

Comment: No estuvo bien hacer 3 preguntas en una sola? Lo hice así porque como se trataban de lo mismo, pensé que era lo mejor. Bueno, ya sé para la próxima. Gracias :)